# NumberFormatException when using FileReader and StringTokenizer

Tags: filereader, tokenize, numberformatexception

The issue I am having is with the "Office" String. I get this: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Office:" I feel like I need to do something else with the parseline down in the tokenizer section? Am I on the right track? I am basically trying to read from a file than I will calculate total sales and write to another file. This is the error I get even when I try to display my people.txt file to an output screen on my GUI. I just need a little advice to where to look to fix this. I have looked up many things but have not came close.

```
public class PersonReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        PersonReader reader = new PersonReader();
        List<person> people = reader.readPeople("people.txt");
        System.out.println(people);

    }

    public List<person> readPeople(String filename) throws IOException {

        File f = new File(filename);
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        List<person> people = new ArrayList<person>();

        String line = breader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            person p = null;

            try {
                p = parseLine(line);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (p == null) {
                System.out.println("This row is bad." + line);
            } else {
                people.add(p);
            }
            line = breader.readLine();
        }

        return people;
    }

    private static person parseLine(String line) {

        int repID;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        double books;
        double paper;
        double office;
        String district;
        String contact;
        String next;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ", ");

        repID = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
        firstName = st.nextToken().trim();
        lastName = st.nextToken().trim();
        books = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken().trim());
        parseLine(line);
        paper = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken().trim());
        parseLine(line);
        office = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken().trim());
        parseLine(line);
        district = st.nextToken().trim();
        parseLine(line);
        contact = st.nextToken().trim();
        parseLine(line);


        if (repID < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        if (firstName.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (lastName.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (books < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        if (paper < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        if (office < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        if (district.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (contact.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        person p = new person();
        p.setRepID(repID);
        p.setFirstName(firstName);
        p.setLastName(lastName);
        p.setBooks(books);
        p.setPaper(paper);
        p.setOffice(office);
        p.setDistrict(district);
        p.setContact(contact);
        return p;

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show some example input?

Comment: 673 John Bobby Office: 12.0 Books: 234.0 Paper: 332.0 SOUTH Visit
This is how it stores to my people.txt file from the GUI when I enter the information. I understand that I am having trouble converting the string to a double. I just cant wrap my head around what to exactly I need to do.

Comment: Seems like the fourth token in your string is "Office:" which can't convert to double. You need to skip over a token.

Comment: Odin!! Thank you! That was so obvious, but just needed to be pointed in the right direction! It works now!